# Does my world map make sense scientifically?

Tags: science-based, map-making

I'm currently working on a world map. This will be used for various things. I'm trying to get it realistic looking and I want it to make sense scientifically. It doesn't have to be 100% perfect, just close enough that it won't matter.

This is just the land masses.
[image: Land Masses]

This is a map including the plate tectonics.
[image: Plate Tectonics]

This shows the mountains, volcanos & trenches.
[image: Details]

Red: Mountain Ranges
Green: Volcano Activity
Dark Blue: Undersea Trenches
Light Blue: Undersea Mountains

For reference, this is my "Pangea"
[image]

On the first map of the landmasses: The landmass to the bottom right I'm imagining having went north around the planet and came back up from the south.

If more information is needed I will be glad to edit the post and add in the relevant info.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane Ah gotcha, so I probably need to add another plate in between and a trench across there?

Comment: Maybe there is an expansion zone on the south-coast or on the east-coast of the other - perhaps a mountain range there. I'll let others with more expertise chime in.

Comment: You've put all the green spots (vulcanism) in the middle of your plates.  I'd expect some more vulcanic activity along your plate boundaries. When there is underseas mountains, you'd have places with vulcanic activity as well. Here's a link about the subject https://www.nationalgeographic.org/article/plate-tectonics-volcanic-activity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect more of a bump where these two plates come together. Like this:

[image]

It would make sense for the chain of islands to be along the fault.
Unless there is a way they could have been formed at the fault and then move away over time. Can that happen?

[image]

Comment: If those are subduction-induced Andesite volcanoes (like Japan and the rest of the Ring of Fire) they'll be a couple hundred km past the actual subduction boundary -- the falling plate has to get deep enough to melt, then tends to go straight up.  Spreading center vulcanism occurs right on the boundary.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Aha so it is possible they can be formed by but not exactly along the boundary. I guess we need to ask God -- Zethnos, are you cool with subduction-induced Andesite volcanoes?

Comment: @Daron Yeah, I'm fine with anything that is scientifically sound, I don't mind changing anything at all. So should I remove this plate entirely then or just move that edge of the plate out towards the other landmass to the north east?

Comment: @Zethnos I'd just add in the bump if it were me. Maybe add more of a 'corner' to the landmass near the intersection to the north, like how the Indian meets the Eurasian and Arabian plates. I won't comment on the other plates other to say they all have the correct bumps.